# cfwebsocket cannot find channels

Tags: coldfusion, websocket, coldfusion-10, cfwebsocket

I have just started a project at work using cfwebsockets. When I attempt to subscribe to the channel I set in the Application file `<cfset this.wschannels = [{name="notify"}]>` I get the following response in chrome:

```
Object {clientid: 540872586, ns: "coldfusion.websocket.channels", reqType: "subscribe", code: -1, type: "response"…}
    clientid: 540872586
    code: -1
    msg: "Channel 'notify' doesn't exist or is not running."
    ns: "coldfusion.websocket.channels"
    reqType: "subscribe"
    type: "response"
    __proto__: Object
```

Why would it not be finding  it?  Here is more of my code for reference.

```
<cfwebsocket name="notify" onOpen="subscribeUser" onMessage="msgHandler" onError="errHandler">

<script>
    function errHandler(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    function msgHandler(message){
        var data = message.data;
        if(data){
        }
    }
    function subscribeUser(){
        console.log(notify);
        notify.subscribe("notify",{name: '#Session.Auth.FirstName#',UserID: '#Session.Auth.UserID#',LocationID: '#Session.Auth.LocationID#'});
    }
    function publish(txt, msgType){
        var msg = {message: txt, UserID: '#Session.Auth.UserID#', type: msgType};
        var headers = {selector: 'LocationID eq "#Session.Auth.LocationID#"'};
        notify.publish('notify',msg, headers);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: can you check if the port is not being blocked? websockets run on port 8575 by default.

Comment: Thanks @Sanjeev. We actually opened it yesterday on both Development and Production so I am sure they are open. It is making the connection. I ran a test using .isConnectionOpen() and it returned `true`... I just thought of something. We only opened the incoming ports. I don't believe we opened the outgoing. I'll try that.